# Is there a plugins for right-to-left of MDB (Material Design Bootstrap)

Tags: material-design, angularjs-material

I'm working on Material Design for angular js.

I want to use in right-to-left mode for persian language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, MDB does not support RTL. I can confirm that RTL is planned in the future. The issue Is That the Bootstrap does not support RTL itself

Comment: Bootstrap only has rtl plug-ins but mdb has problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the materials and not bootstrap.
it support rtl
by adding to css:

`* {
    direction: rtl;
  }`

regards,
Yehuda.