# material design bootstrap right to left Direction

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap, farsi

I am using Material Design Bootstrap for React and iIwant to use it for Persian mood.
Is there any solution for right to left direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a plugins for right-to-left of MDB (Material Design Bootstrap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588009/is-there-a-plugins-for-right-to-left-of-mdb-material-design-bootstrap)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> only add this CSS class to your classes  i had a problem with Label on
>   the MDBInput in Material Design Bootstrap so i finally add this class
>   to Label Class.

```
.md-form label {
left: unset !important;
display: block;
```

};